# Android unable to display chooser

Tags: android, android-activity

When calling startActivity with a configured chooser intent, the Android chooser is not displaying any list of applications which can handle the intent.  I suspect my handling activity is not configured correctly, but not combination of intent-filters has cause it to display.
Disclaimer:  This is for an online course.

```
static private final String URL = "http://www.google.com";
Intent baseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URL));
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(baseIntent, CHOOSER_TEXT);
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

The handling activity:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

A chooser never displays.  Android launches chrome instead.
This happens both on emulator, and on my touchpad.

Comment: Have the devices selected Chrome to handle all the browser intents? You could clear/check that by going into the Chrome application through settings and all application. And "Clear defaults" if it's set to handle the intents.

Comment: I have looked at Applications > All > Browser, but not seeing any setting related to intents.  No defaults were changed, so it did not offer to let me clear them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your intent-filter as below:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```